# Error implementing Interface Methods in Class

Tags: java, interface

I'm working on a simple project using Interfaces, but I am having an issue making my class conform to the interface.

My thought process is that since Article implements IDedObject, I should be able to pass an Article as a parameter in my overridden functions within my Article Class definition. Unfortunately this throws the error "The type Article must implement the inherited abstract method IDedObject.getID()"

**Interface**

```
public interface IDedObject{
    public int getID(IDedObject object);
    public void printID(IDedObject object);
}
```

**Class**

```
public class Article implements IDedObject{
private int articleID;
private String articleName;
private String authorName;

@Override
public int getID(Article article){
    return article.articleID;
}

@Override
public void printID(Article article){
    System.out.println(article.articleID);
}
}
```

What is missing or incorrect?

Comment: Your interface itself doesn't make sense. Why are its methods taking parameters? Why of its own type??

Comment: Please post your complete requirements because I think that you're missing first principles here.

Comment: Your getID and printID should take an IDedObject as the parameter.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I modeled the interface off the one from the Java docs. You can see that the Relatable interface contains a method which uses a Relatable object as a parameter. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html)

Comment: You can't change the type when you override; by definition, an override requires an identical signature with a super-type method.

Comment: zcoon: that still doesn't tell us **why** you've modeled it this way. Tell us more about your actual requirements. What this code does.

Comment: In the example the method with the Rectangle parameter is only for **comparison** of two objects of the same type. Your code shows nothing of this at all. Yeah, I'm sure that your interface is broken and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a guess since we don't have your requirements, but I think that your interface is broken, that your methods shouldn't require parameters much less parameters of its own type. Consider changing:

```
public interface IDedObject{
    public int getID(IDedObject object);
    public void printID(IDedObject object);
}
```

to:

```
public interface IDedObject{
    public int getID();
    public void printID();
}
```

Then the implementation would be trivial

```
public class Article implements IDedObject{
    private int articleID;
    private String articleName;
    private String authorName;

    // constructor and other getter and setter methods here

    @Override
    public int getID(){
        return articleID;
    }

    @Override
    public void printID(){
        System.out.println("" + articleID);
    }
}
```

As for your compiler error -- the signature of any overridden methods must match those of the interface methods. So for instance in your Rectangle example in your link, if you extend that class or interface, then the method parameter must take the interface parameter as declared in the interface.

For example, say you had the following interface:

```
public interface FooInterface {
    int getValue();
    void printValue();
    int difference(FooInterface fi);
}
```

The concrete class that implements this interface **must** use a FooInterface parameter for the difference method. For example:

```
class FooClass implements FooInterface {

    private int value;

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public void printValue() {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    @Override  // can't use FooClass for parameter here
    public int difference(FooInterface fi) {
        return value - fi.getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: I had initially designed it this way, but then there is an error within my Article class "The type Article must implement the inherited abstract method IDedObject.getID()" , which to me implies that I can't pass a parameter into the function, right?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @zcoon: you should only use a method that takes an IDedObject if you need to compare the current object with another IDedObject, for instance if you wanted to make the class Comparable.

Comment: @CKing: the question is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) and I'm trying to solve the underlying problem itself, and not solve the direct question which is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels .. Embarrassingly, I had blanked on the fact that I could access Article's properties without passing in an instance of Article to the methods defined within itself.

Comment: @zcoon: see edit to answer in attempt to answer both your original question and the xy problem question.

Comment: An answer must always address the direct question and optionally answer the indirect question. This answer did exactly the opposite and thus my question to you was not out of place *How did you answer the question with your initial answer?*

Comment: It's the other way around. Yes we should answer both (and I've updated my answer to do so), but primarily we should help solve the xy issue first and foremost. Please see the [various meta questions on this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels).

Answer (score 2):

The `getID` and `putID` methods are not being *overriden* in `Article` class.  They are being *overloaded*.

When you change the parameter type, it is an *overload* and not an *override*. This may seem a bit confusing at first but the key thing to understand is that `Article` inherits the two methods from the interface. When you change the parameter type, you are actually *overloading* these inherited methods rather than *overriding* them.

That said, the purpose of a getter method is to return the value of an instance variable and optionally perform some operations on this value before returning it.

Comment: So a getter method takes a parameter? This does not make sense.

Comment: I am only answering the direct question being asked which is *My thought process is that since Article implements IDedObject, I should be able to pass an Article as a parameter in my overridden functions within my Article Class definition. Unfortunately this throws the error "The type Article must implement the inherited abstract method IDedObject.getID()*

Comment: Probably the best solution would be to answer both, the direct question and the XY Problem issue.

Comment: Answering the direct question is mandatory. Any answer without that is incorrect.

Comment: Other way around. Yes we should answer both (and I've updated my answer to do so), but primarily we should help solve the xy issue first and foremost. Please see the [various meta questions on this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels).

Answer (score 0):

Your override

```
public int getID(Article article)
```

Doesn't override the method of the interface because of a mismatch in the parameter - it should be `IDedObject`. 
You could use a generic parameter to `IDedObject`, and use a wildcard constraint to make sure it implements `IDedObject`, but as far as I know, there is no way to tell Java that you want to inherit with the same type as the wildcard.

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast to the implementation of the interface (Article). The method signatures in the interface and the class need to be the same.

```
public interface IDedObject{
    public int getID(IDedObject object);
    public void printID(IDedObject object);
}

public class Article implements IDedObject{
    private int articleID;
    private String articleName;
    private String authorName;

    @Override
    public int getID(IDedObject object) {
        Article article = (Article) object;
        return article.articleID;
    }

    @Override
    public void printID(IDedObject object) {
        Article article = (Article) object;
        System.out.println(article.articleID);

    }
}
```